# Javascript var inside loop is not defined

Tags: javascript

I bet tons of you guys had this issue and it may be called "Javascript implicit global var" or something like that. Basically, I'm trying to write a validation tool and I have a class `MIMIRxErrorHandler`. It has 2 methods, `validate()`, which validates all fields, and `validateSpecificField()`, which validates each field. One strange thing is that in the method `validate()`, it always throws the following error:

```
rule is not defined for line: "let fieldName = rule.name;"
```

Could someone help me get through this? Thanks a lot. The whole code is below:

```js
class MIMIRxErrorHandler {
  constructor(props) {}

  validate(rules) {
    var errorMessages = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
      let rule = rules[i];
      let fieldName = rule.name;
      const validationResult = this.validateSpecificField(
        rule.value,
        rule.rules
      );
      if (validationResult.length > 0) {
        errorMessages[fieldName] = `${fieldName} ${validationResult.join(",")}`;
      }
    }
    return errorMessages;
  }

  validateSpecificField(value, rules) {
    const isPresence = rules.presence;
    const rangeRule = rules.range;
    const regexRule = rules.regex;
    const otherNotAllowedValuesRule = rule.otherNotAllowedValues;
    var errorMessages = [];
    //  ***  range  ***
    if (isPresence) {
      if (value === null || value === undefined || value === NaN) {
        errorMessages.push(` cannot be blank`);
      }
    }
    if (rangeRule !== null && rangeRule !== undefined) {
      const type = rangeRule.type;
      if (type == "number") {
        value = parseFloat(value);
        if (value > rangeRule.maxLength || value < rangeRule.minLength) {
          errorMessages.push(
            ` between ${rangeRule.minLength} and ${rangeRule.maxLength}`
          );
        }
      } else if (type == "string") {
        value = value.toString();
        if (
          value.length > rangeRule.maxLength ||
          value.length < rangeRule.minLength
        ) {
          errorMessages.push(
            ` between ${rangeRule.minLength} and ${rangeRule.maxLength}`
          );
        }
      }
    }
    if (regexRule !== null && regexRule !== undefined) {
      if (!value.match(regexRule.pattern)) {
        errorMessages.push(regexRule.regexErrorMessage);
      }
    }
    if (otherNotAllowedValuesRule.includes(value)) {
      errorMessages.push(" is invalid");
    }
    return errorMessages;
  }
}

rules = () => {
  return [
    {
      name: "first_name",
      value: "John",
      rules: {
        presence: true,
        range: {
          type: "string",
          minLength: 10,
          maxLength: 200,
        },
        regex: {
          pattern: /^\w+$/,
          regexErrorMessage: " should only be letters",
        },
        otherNotAllowedValues: ["0", ""],
      },
    },
    {
      name: "age",
      value: "23",
      rules: {
        presence: true,
        range: {
          type: "number",
          minLength: 1,
          maxLength: 3,
        },
        regex: {
          pattern: /^\d+$/,
          regexErrorMessage: " should be only digits",
        },
        otherNotAllowedValues: ["0", ""],
      },
    },
  ];
};

var a = new MIMIRxErrorHandler();
console.log(a.validate(this.rules()));
```

Comment: don't use var, use let and const

Comment: @O.o—irrelevant.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property). Since it seems *rule* can be undefined, you need to test before accessing any of its properties like `if (rule)` or more strictly `if (typeof rule != 'undefined')`.

Comment: Is `rules` a class method? It doesn't appear so in your code. If it is, the `this` context in `a.validate(this.rules())` doesn't refer to `a`. If `rules()` always returns an array, it might be better to set the array to `MIMIRxErrorHandler.rules` and access it via `this` inside of your methods. You might also need to bind your class methods in your constructor.

Comment: good point @khan

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in the code:

1. `const otherNotAllowedValuesRule = rule.otherNotAllowedValues;`
   **ReferenceError**: rule is not defined.
   ***change*:**
   `const otherNotAllowedValuesRule = rules.otherNotAllowedValues;`
2. `if (!value.match(regexRule.pattern)) {`
   **TypeError**: value.match is not a function
   ***change*:**
   `if (typeof value == 'string' && !value.match(regexRule.pattern)) {
       errorMessages.push(regexRule.regexErrorMessage);
   }
   if (typeof value == 'number' && !value.toString().match(regexRule.pattern)) {
       errorMessages.push(regexRule.regexErrorMessage);
   }`

**NOTE**: I am assuming `rules` is a method of class `MIMIRxErrorHandler`.

```
var a = new  MIMIRxErrorHandler()
console.log(a.validate(a.rules()));
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to using a value created as an item of a list or other objects it's always important to ensure that there's value in them prior to using them in your operations.

Commonly, you test for data using `if(rule)` which literally checks for value within rule.

Or perhaps before you even get that far, it would also help you to ensure that `rules : type []` has values in it by testing `if(rules.length > 0` before you try to accesing any of it's items.